# PHP: Check that a string doesn't contain any special characters but periods

Tags: php, regex, string, dns

I need to check if a string is valid domain name or host address. This is because I need to block all unfriendly commands from the given string.

One generic solution could be pinging the given address and see if it responses but unfortunately in my case this is not an option.

I think that possible characters are A-Z, a-z, all numbers and the dot '.' so preg_match function could be a way to go. My knowledge of regex is about zero but I managed to find out the following line to check everything else but the dots.

```
preg_match("/([a-zA-Z0-9])/", $mystring);
```

So could you guys help me out for the right regex syntax to allow the characters mentioned above? Or if you come up with a better solution to block that possible security issue (the string will end up in shell_exec function so it's quite critical) please spit it out. Thanks! :)

EDIT: So possible inputs are for example a typical IP address: 123.123.123.123 or a domain name mydomain.com or corp.mydomain.xx.com. The number of dots is not constant.

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Show examples of the data format that you will receive. Like 111.111.111.111

Comment: you can use `filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)`.

Comment: examples of possible inputs: a typical ip address: 111.111.111.111, domain name: somestring.computername.com or computername.com

Comment: ...the number of dots is not constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the PHP filter to check if a domain name or host is valid. Not sure if it does everything you need:

```
filter_var($urlToFilter, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== false)
```

Comment: This looks interesting. I'm going to try this first. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't seem to work for me as it doesn't allow addresses without protocol definitions http, ftp etc... Possible inputs in my case are f.e 111.111.111.111 and dev.mydomain.tm.com. I found a filter also for IP address but still I need to validate domain names without protocols given. :)

Comment: Cool. Check out the other validators though, that may help: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php. Up to your business rules, but I'd normally add a protocol before storing it, so this worked for me. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I finally ended up using FILTER_VALIDATE_URL and FILTER_VALIDATE_IP together with preg_match

Answer (score 1):

for a domain:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.([a-zA-Z]{2,})
```

Answer (score 0):

dKen's suggestion to use filters worked together with the following preg_matches:

```
$chars = preg_match("/^([a-z\d](-*[a-z\d])*)(\.([a-z\d](-*[a-z\d])*))*$/i", $domain_name); //valid chars check
$length = preg_match("/^.{1,253}$/", $domain_name); //overall length check
$labels = preg_match("/^[^\.]{1,63}(\.[^\.]{1,63})*$/", $domain_name); //length of each label
```